# jQuery - Templates - How to do a timestamp compare

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

I'm using jQuery Templates, and want to do a timestamp compare. Is this possible?

I was hoping to do something along the lines of:

```
<script id='mytemplate' type='text/html'>
{{if 2011-03-02T14:15:04-08:00 > Current_timestamp}}
New
{{else}}
not new
{{/if}}
</script>
```

possible? Thanks

**Update, realized client-side time will not work and need to pass the current server time: Here is the latest :**

```
<script id="comment" type="text/html">

    {{if new Date(cmtModel.conv_last_reply()) > new Date(created_at) }}
        yep
    {{else}}
        nope
    {{/if}}

</script>
```

Where cmtModel.conv_last_reply() is coming from KnockoutJS, and created_at is when the comment was created.

Comment: do you want to compare against server side time or client side time?

Answer (score 2):

You can compare JavaScript Date objects.

**UPDATE** looks like template gets caught on directly comparing dates inside the if. You can do something like this:

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    {{if item}}
    New
    {{else}}
    not new
    {{/if}}
</script>
```

Then your javascript could look like this:

```
var dateDiff = new Date('2011-03-02T14:15:04-08:00') > new Date();
$('#template').tmpl(dateDiff);
```

See example: http://jsfiddle.net/yads/ScwTP/2/

Comment: Thanks Yads, tried that and I get:  jquery-1.5.1.js:869Uncaught TypeError: Object Wed Mar 02 2011 14:35:35 GMT-0800 (PST) has no method 'call'

Comment: You were right I needed to use server time not clientside time, as the timezones get messed up. I just updated the Q with the latest code, still errroing . ideas?

Comment: Interesting thanks for the jsfiddle, but this is adding a lot of complexity don't you think? The date comparison isn't at that high of a level it's a minor thing that doesn't effect much, just the addition of a class if applicable. Any other ideas on how to do a date compare w/o adding or changing so much?

Comment: @AnApprentice, no idea, I didn't think `template` would get tripped up like that. I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish so it's hard for me to say whether or not this is overkill.

Comment: I ended up just moving the comparison to an outside function of the template that worked pretty nicely. I just call ${cmtDateCompare(d1, d2)} and the function returns back a class to add if there is one. Problem is that I think the above only does a date comparison, and not a date/time comparison!